# Does load-order and parallel-load work in combination in AWS DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I have two tables let's call it `tbl_parent` and `tbl_child` in Microsoft SQL Server, and trying to transfer the data of these tables to AWS aurora PostgreSQL.

Here `tbl_child` has a foreign key reference on `tbl_parent`, so to avoid FK issues during the full load I have mentioned higher load-order for `tbl_parent` than table `tbl_child`. The same was suggested in aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Selections.html).

So with that load-order setting, I was expecting that the data would only be inserted into `tbl_child` after the complete insertion is done in `tbl_parent` .

Also I want to do a parallel load into child table, so I have specified table-settings rule to perform parallel load as suggested in aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Tablesettings.html)

For some reason I see the data into `tbl_child` is getting inserted even before `tbl_parent` load is complete, and I'm getting Foreign key issues like below ...

> 2021-07-14T18:53:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]W:  Load command output: psql:
> /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2: no version information available (required
> by /rdsdbbin/awsdms/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2) psql:
> /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2: no version information available (required
> by /rdsdbbin/awsdms/lib/libkrb5.so.3) ERROR:  insert or update on
> table "tbl_child" violates foreign key constraint
> "tbl_child_tbl_parent_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (parent_id)=(1468137) is not
> present in table "tbl_parent".  (csv_target.c:1018)

In case if it helps please find the mapping rules json below

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "101",
            "rule-name": "101",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "dbo",
                "table-name": "tbl_parent"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": [],
            "load-order": 2
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "102",
            "rule-name": "102",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "dbo",
                "table-name": "tbl_child"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": [],
            "load-order": 1
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "table-settings",
            "rule-id": "131",
            "rule-name": "Parallel_Range_Child",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "dbo",
                "table-name": "tbl_child"
            },
            "parallel-load": {
                "type": "ranges",
                "columns": [
                    "child_id"
                ],
                "boundaries": [
                    [
                        "100"
                    ],
                    [
                        "200"
                    ],
                    [
                        "300"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strictly control load order, for example, finished one table then another table, you must set maxFullloadsubtasks=1.

Actually, to avoid such issues one way is to disable FK/RI checking in target db, such options are a/v in SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle, but seems not a/v in PgSQL. Anyway your steps for full + CDC using DMS maybe:

1. Create the basic table schema including primary key in target db
2. DMS full load
3. Create FK/RIs/index and other db objects
4. DMS CDC